# How to implement Connect and Play

Tags: google-cast

I have an app that streams live audio and it will connect and play through the chromecast with no errors (play and connect).  So now I am trying to figure out how to play through the chromecast if the user connects first before playing the audio.  Per the UI guidelines you have to display a cast button on all activities.  So my app has a main activity with 2 play buttons for different stations and also the cast button and then has another activity for when the station is playing after you select which station you want to play (ie the ip address gets selected depending on which button you choose).  In this activity's onRouteSelected() I am then switching to the chromecast and stopping local playback on the device.

My questions is how do I call the onRouteSelected() to get the chromecast going if the chromecast has already been connected in the previous activity??  I have looked at the sample apps and cannot figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [CastVideos-android](https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-android) sample project that uses the [CastCompanionLibrary](https://github.com/googlecast/CastCompanionLibrary-android) to maintain state and manage most of the cast related job. You can either use the library or see how things are done there if you want to do it yourself.

If you are already connected to a chromecast device, you are not going to get a new call to onRouteSelected() so you need to maintain the state of connectivity across your activities (say, in a singleton or in your Application), that is what CastCompanionLibrary does.

Comment: Ali thank you for the reply.  I have imported the CCL for use and have changed my code.  I cannot even get my app to load, it throws a null exception "Application ID cannot be null".  I assume this is referring to the receiver app id?  I have it set in a string.  I am using the default media receiver app.  <string name="app_id">CC1AD845</string>

Comment: So it is because the CastApplication onCreate() is not getting called so it is null.  I have looked over the CastVideos many times and I do not see what I am missing????

Comment: I had to add this to the manifest: android:name="com.joebutt.mouseworldradio.CastApplication"